# Using xaml states to change window size programatically

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visualstates

I have created 2 states for the main window of the program (big and small) and i have added a tabcontrol with 2 tab items. I want to use the big state to change the size of the window when i am in tab1 and small state to change the size of window when i am in tab2. I used the following code but an unable to change the window size.

```
private void Changes(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (tab1.IsSelected)
        {
            VisualStateManager.GoToElementState(window, "Big", true);
            b1.Text = Convert.ToString(i);
        }
        else
        {
            VisualStateManager.GoToElementState(window, "Small", true);
            b1.Text = Convert.ToString(i);
        }
    }
```

the method Changes is the tabcontrol's SelectionChanged event.

I cannot find what i did wrong here.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.sizetocontent(v=vs.110).aspx what is your setting for your Window.SetToContent? Is it manual?

Comment: I have not modified its default value so think its automatic